# Set theory: partially ordered set convex set question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A subset $C$ of a partially ordered set is called convex if it satisfies the following conditions: if $a \in C, b \in C$ and $a \le x \le b$, then $x \in C$. Let $f:A \to B$ be an increasing function, where $A$ and $B$ are partially ordered sets. Prove that if $C$ is a convex subset of $B$, then $f^{-1}(C)$ is a convex subset of $A$.

From What I know, I understand that

Since $C$ is a convex subset of $B$ and $f$ is an increasing function,

$\forall x,y \in A, x \le y \implies f(x) \le f(y)$

We need to show that $f^{-1}(C)$ is a convex set. But does it mean I have to show there is a $y \in f^{-1}(C)$?

I am lost with this. Any help would be appreiciated.

Comment: Is $f$ bijective? Or else $f^{-1}(C)$ may not be well-defined.

Comment: The questions does not say $f$ is bijective, so I think I cannot have that assumption

Comment: @DHMO We don't need $f^{-1}$ to be a map, in order to prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a, b \in f^{-1}(C)$, and $x \in A$ be such that $a \leq x \leq b$.
Then $f(a) \leq f(x) \leq f(b)$.
But $f(a), f(b) \in C$ and thus, $f(x) \in C$, yielding $x \in f^{-1}(C)$.

Comment: When do you use the fact that $f$ is increasing?

Comment: Let $A=\{1,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$ ordered naturally, $f=\{(1,1),(3,3)\}$, Then $f$ is increasing (strictly), $C=B$ is convex but $f^{-1}(C)$ does not exist, so is not a set, let alone convex.

Comment: @CrusoJames I use the fact that $f$ is increasing in the second line: if $a \leq x \leq b$ then $f(a) \leq f(x) \leq f(b)$.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you!

Comment: @CiaPan I think it is quite common to define $f^{-1}(C) = \{ x \in A : f(x) \in C \}$. So in your example, $f^{-1}(C) = A$.

Answer (score 0):

$f^{-1}(C)$ is convex provided it exists! However, the problem statement does not imply that every $C\subseteq B$ is an image of some subset of $A$. Suppose $f$ constant, that is $f(A)$ is a singleton, and $C$ contains an element different from the $f$ value...